# Unable to do a urlSession request with Combine

Tags: swift, combine

Unable to get `Data` using `Combine`, nothing is printed on the console.

```
struct RepositoryElement: Codable {}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/brunosilva808/repos")!

        let repos = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: [Repository].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in // 5
                print(completion)
            }, receiveValue: { repositories in
                print("brunosilva808 has \(repositories.count) repositories")
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you storing your cancellable?

Comment: @Andrew, this is the full code. So, that may be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because your `repo` variable is going out of scope and thus your network request is being cancelled. You need to hold on to your request so make a variable in your ViewController to keep hold of it.

If you do something like this then it should work. You'll need to import Combine because `AnyCancellable` is part of Combine.

```
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/brunosilva808/repos")!

        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: [Repository].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in // 5
                print(completion)
            }, receiveValue: { repositories in
                print("brunosilva808 has \(repositories.count) repositories")
            })

    }
}
```

I couldn't check if it decodes properly because you didn't include the Repository struct.